# Flattening chained datasets

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've got a dataset, which looks like that:

```
+-----+-----+
|prev |next |
+-----+-----+
|    A|    B|
|    B|    C|
|    C|    D|
+-----+-----+
```

So basically values can form chains that column `next` from one row is the same as value `previous` from another row.

And I want to "flatten" it into another dataset, which looks like:

```
+-----+-----+
|prev |next |
+-----+-----+
|   A |    B|
|   A |    C|
|   A |    D|
+-----+-----+
```

Graphically I can be displayed as transforming chain:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

to

```
A -> B
A -> C
A -> D
```

I do this transformation because I need to join that computed dataset with two other datasets using columns `prev` and `next`.

I created a working recursive solution:

```
public Dataset<Row> flatten(Dataset<Row> transfers) {

    Dataset<Row> notChainingTransfers = transfers.as("left").join(
            transfers.as("right"),
            functions.expr("left.prev = right.next"), "leftanti"
    );

    Dataset<Row> chainingTransfers = transfers.as("left").join(
            transfers.as("right"),
            functions.expr("left.pre = right.next")
    ).select("right.prev", "left.next");

    Dataset<Row> union = notChainingTransfers.union(chainingTransfers);

    if (chainingTransfers.count() > 0) {
        return flatten(union);
    } else {
        return union;
    }
}
```

But I feel it's not very pretty nor efficient. It also has a big drawback, that when I receive incorrect data forming a circular chain, then it goes into infinite recursion:

```
 A -> B -> A
```

A situation like this shouldn't happen, but it would be nice if I had a solution, that could handle problems like that.

I'm looking for some tips on how to improve my solution or for alternative approaches.

Comment: So basically you're  computing [connected components](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bapache-spark%5d%20connectedComponents) aren't you?

Comment: @user10958683 Yes, I guess you're right. I need to check `graphx`.